# What does changing "max-chained-neighbor-updates" server property do?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have looked around the internet for an answer but everywhere it just has the text from the Minecraft changelog.

https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/article/the-wild-update-out-today-java

> Added server property max-chained-neighbor-updates to limit the amount
> of consecutive neighbor updates before skipping additional ones
>
> - Negative values remove the limit

I don't know what this neighbor update is referring to, and why it's defaulted to a big number of 1000000. Why was it important enough to be added as a setting?

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be useful against things like lag machines, but here's a list of neighbor updates

Neighbor changed (NC) updates (aka neighbor changed, update neighbors, redstone update) are the most widely known type of block updates, and are mainly used for redstone components.

Some blocks (mainly redstone components) sends more NC updates other than general NC updates when changing.

Taken from the wiki, see the [link](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Block_update#Neighbor_changed_update) for more details.